# Reading terraform variable from file

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

In terraform, long keys can be specified as follows:

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "foo-policy" {
    role = "${aws_iam_role.foo-role.name}"
    name = "foo-policy"

    policy = <<EOF
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents",
                "logs:DescribeLogStreams"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
EOF
}
```

This is a common pattern for IAM policy documents. The approach is documented [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/variables.html) and is the example given in the [AWS IAM role policy page on terraform](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/iam_role_policy.html). Is there a way to instead read the document from an external file?

This has numerous advantages:

- you can use tools to generate the policy
- you can use linting tools to validate the policy JSON. Also editor syntax highlighting will work, showing JSON mistakes like trailing commas.
- you can use more advanced tools to validate the policy document syntax

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use terraform's [template_file](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/template/d/file.html) data source for this. Simply write your policy out to a file in a path that your terraform scripts can access, and then create a template_file data source that references it. For example:

```
data "template_file" "policy" {
  template = "${file("somepath/my-policy.json")}"
}
```

And then, in foo-policy, you would render it like so:

```
policy = "${data.template_file.policy.rendered}"
```

An additional benefit of template_file is that you can interpolate variables within the referenced file. For example, you could have variables like `${IAMUser}` or `${AWSAccountNumber}` in your policy and pass it in via the template_file vars option, which would allow you to reuse the policy file.

### Further Reading

- [Terraform Docs - Configuring Data Sources](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/data-sources.html)

Comment: Additionally, if the separate file is a literal IAM policy document (no Terraform template interpolations) you can use the `file` function directly in the `policy` argument to `aws_iam_role_policy`.

Answer (score 1):

In Terraform 0.12 and later there are special functions to read out files:

- [file](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/file.html) reads the contents of a file at the given path and returns them as a string.
- [templatefile](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/templatefile.html) function offers a built-in mechanism for rendering a template from a file.

Use that functions instead of [template_file](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/template/latest/docs/data-sources/file) data source.

```
    resource "aws_instance" "ami-example" {
      ami           = "ami-0c55b159cbfafe1f0"
      instance_type = "t2.micro"
      vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.instance.id]
      user_data     = <<-EOF
              #!/bin/bash
              echo "${file("index.html")}" > index.html
              nohup busybox httpd -f -p 8080 &
              EOF
      tags = {
        "source" = "terraform"
        "Name"   = "tf-ami-example"
      }
   }
```